# Jquery Collapsible Nav Menu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have recently stumbled across this code. It turns my menu into a collapsible list on mobile view - and toggles it open and closed by clicking on the menu header. However, once opened - I would like this list to close once a list item is clicked.

```js
jQuery(".nav-folderized h3").click(function(){
      jQuery(this).parent(".nave").toggleClass("open"); 
  });
```

```css
.ftr__list {
    margin-left: 9%;
margin-right: 9%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 781px) {
    
/**nav-expand for footer with head and ul**/
    .ftr__list {
    margin-left: 2%;
margin-right: 2%;
}

.nav-folderized .nave h3 { cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cacfda;
        padding: 10px !important;
}
.nav-folderized ul { max-height: 0; overflow:hidden; transition: max-height .3s ease; }
.nav-folderized .nave h3:after { content: "+"; float: right; }
.nav-folderized .nave.open h3:after { content: "-"; }
.nav-folderized .nave.open ul { height:auto; max-height: 500px; transition: max-height .3s ease !important;  border-bottom: 1px solid #cacfda !important;
}
/**nav-expand for footer with head and ul**/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-folderized">
<div class="ftr__list nave col-sm-3">
    <h3 class="widget-title">Account Navigation</h3>

<ul class="menu">
      <a class="ajax-link" href="#"><li>Item 1</li></a>
      <a class="ajax-link" href="#"><li>Item 2</li></a>
      <a class="ajax-link" href="#"><li>Item 1</li></a>
</ul>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you wanted?

```js
jQuery(".nav-folderized h3").click(function(){
      jQuery(this).parent(".nave").toggleClass("open"); 
  });
  
jQuery(".ajax-link").click(function(){
      jQuery(".nave").removeClass("open"); 
  });
```

```css
.ftr__list {
    margin-left: 9%;
margin-right: 9%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 781px) {
    
/**nav-expand for footer with head and ul**/
    .ftr__list {
    margin-left: 2%;
margin-right: 2%;
}

.nav-folderized .nave h3 { cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cacfda;
        padding: 10px !important;
}
.nav-folderized ul { max-height: 0; overflow:hidden; transition: max-height .3s ease; }
.nav-folderized .nave h3:after { content: "+"; float: right; }
.nav-folderized .nave.open h3:after { content: "-"; }
.nav-folderized .nave.open ul { height:auto; max-height: 500px; transition: max-height .3s ease !important;  border-bottom: 1px solid #cacfda !important;
}
/**nav-expand for footer with head and ul**/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-folderized">
<div class="ftr__list nave col-sm-3">
    <h3 class="widget-title">Account Navigation</h3>

<ul class="menu">
      <a class="ajax-link" href="#"><li>Item 1</li></a>
      <a class="ajax-link" href="#"><li>Item 2</li></a>
      <a class="ajax-link" href="#"><li>Item 1</li></a>
</ul>

</div>
</div>
```